# Dask distributed calculation performance drop in loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, distributed

I'm new to Dask and still trying to figure out how to get this running smoothly. I've been experimenting with `future` API and I get some surprising results.

I have a simple `while` loop in my code that call the function `cpi5`. When I `%timeit` the execution of the fucntion I get :

```
%timeit min(cpci5(x,N,M,n,lciw,uciw))
6.74 s ± 178 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Now I've run the same function but using a distributed sheduler in dask and I get this :

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client= Client()
%timeit B.append(client.submit(cpci5,x,N,M,n,lciw,uciw)); bb = np.array(client.gather(B))
29 ms ± 6.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So far so good, the expected improvement is there but when I time the execution of the loop itself where the function is called, I barely get any difference and they both run in approximately 19s. (I've profile the initial loop and more than 90% of the computation time is due to the function so the improvement should be there.)

The results are coherent and identical.

What could cause such a difference ?

You'll find below the relevant piece of code.
PS : I've already gone as far as i could in code optimization but it's not enough in my case.

```
N = 392
n = 326
x = np.arange(0,n+1)

if np.floor(n/2) == n/2: 
         xvalue = int(n/2 +1)
     else :                   
         xvalue = int((n+1)/2)

     aa = np.arange(lciw[xvalue-1],np.floor(N/2)).astype(int)

lciw :
array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
        13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,
        27,  28,  29,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  40,  41,
        42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  49,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,
        57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,
        72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  86,
        87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98, 100, 101,
       102, 103, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 114, 115, 116,
       117, 118, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131,
       132, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 146, 147,
       148, 149, 150, 151, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 159, 160, 161, 162,
       163, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 178,
       179, 180, 181, 182, 184, 185, 186, 189, 188, 190, 191, 192, 193,
       194, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 208, 209,
       210, 211, 212, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 221, 222, 223, 225,
       226, 227, 228, 229, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 237, 238, 239, 240,
       241, 243, 244, 245, 246, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 254, 255, 256,
       257, 258, 260, 261, 262, 263, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 271, 272,
       273, 274, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 282, 283, 284, 285, 287, 288,
       289, 290, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 298, 299, 300, 301, 303, 304,
       305, 306, 308, 309, 310, 311, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 319, 320,
       321, 322, 324, 325, 326, 327, 329, 330, 331, 332, 334, 335, 336,
       338, 339, 340, 341, 343, 344, 345, 346, 348, 349, 350, 351, 353,
       354, 355, 357, 358, 359, 360, 362, 363, 364, 366, 367, 368, 369,
       371, 372, 373, 375, 376, 377, 379, 380, 382, 383, 384, 386, 387,
       389, 390])

uciw :
array([2,   3,   5,   6,   8,   9,  10,  12,  13,  15,  16,  17,  19,
        20,  21,  23,  24,  25,  26,  28,  29,  30,  32,  33,  34,  35,
        37,  38,  39,  41,  42,  43,  44,  46,  47,  48,  49,  51,  52,
        53,  54,  56,  57,  58,  60,  61,  62,  63,  65,  66,  67,  68,
        70,  71,  72,  73,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  81,  82,  83,  84,
        86,  87,  88,  89,  91,  92,  93,  94,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100,
       102, 103, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109, 110, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116,
       118, 119, 120, 121, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 129, 130, 131, 132,
       134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 146, 147, 148,
       149, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 163, 164,
       165, 166, 167, 169, 170, 171, 172, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 180,
       181, 182, 183, 184, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 192, 193, 194, 195,
       196, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 204, 203, 206, 207, 208, 210, 211,
       212, 213, 214, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226,
       227, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 241, 242,
       243, 244, 245, 246, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 254, 255, 256, 257,
       258, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272,
       274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 287, 288,
       289, 290, 291, 292, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 301, 302, 303,
       304, 305, 306, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 315, 316, 317, 318,
       319, 320, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 330, 331, 332, 333,
       334, 335, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 345, 346, 347, 348,
       349, 350, 351, 352, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 363,
       364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377,
       378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390,
       391, 392])

def cpci5(x,N,M,n,lciw,uciw):

    f = np.vectorize(hypergeom.pmf)
    idd = np.vectorize(ind)

    X, m = np.meshgrid(x,M)    
    kk = idd(m,lciw,uciw) * f(X, N, m, n) #idd just implement a test lciw<= m <=uciw 

    return min(pd.Series(kk.sum(axis=1))) 


M = np.arange(0,N+1) # Initial implementation of the function
    ii = 0
    while (ii <len(aa)+1):
        lciw[xvalue-1] = aa[ii]
        uciw[xvalue-1] = N - aa[ii]

        bb = min(cpci5(x,N,M,n,lciw,uciw))

        if bb >= 1-alpha:
            ii1 = ii
            ii += 1

        else :
            ii = len(aa)+1

    lciw[xvalue-1] = aa[ii1]
    uciw[xvalue-1] = N - lciw[xvalue-1]


M = np.arange(0,N+1) # Distributed version
     ii = 0
     B = []
     while (ii <len(aa)):
         lciw[xvalue-1] = aa[ii]
         uciw[xvalue-1] = N - aa[ii]

         B.append(client.submit(cpci5,x,N,M,n,lciw,uciw))
         ii += 1

     bb = np.array(client.gather(B))
     ii1 = len(bb[bb>1-alpha])-1

     lciw[xvalue-1] = aa[ii1]
     uciw[xvalue-1] = N - lciw[xvalue-1]
```

Comment: Are you sure the two versions of the loop call the same function? In the serial version, you are calling `cpci`. In the parallel version - `cpci5`. Also, if you often `submit()` small chunks of work and then `gather()` them, the overhead may become large enough to swamp any benefit from the parallel execution.

Comment: Sorry it's the same function it was a typo. If it's the overhead of the `submit()` how come it doesn't show in the `%timeit` loop ? Would you have any recomendations on how to amend the code ? Thanks !